# How to process *.js and *.min.js bower files in gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, bower

In my gulp file to inject bower components I have this bad style code duplication. But I do not have any ideas how to get rid of it.

Generally speaking we cannot say just `bower_components/**/*.js` because we don't want to import all files, plus for production we want to import just `.min` files. Again. I cannot guaranty that every package I use have `.js` and `.min.js` files. So just `*.js` and `*.min.js` may not work.

```
gulp.task('inject', () => {
let sources = gulp.src([
        // jquery
        'public/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
        // bootstrap
        'public/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
        'public/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
        // angular
        'public/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
        'public/bower_components/angular/angular-csp.css',
        // angular route
        'public/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
    ],{read: false});

let min_sources = gulp.src([
        // jquery
        'public/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        // bootstrap
        'public/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
        'public/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
        // angular
        'public/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js',
        'public/bower_components/angular/angular-csp.css',
        // angular route
        'public/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js',
    ],{read: false});

return gulp.src('public/build/index.html')
    .pipe(gulpif(!argv.production, inject(sources, {relative: true})))
    .pipe(gulpif(argv.production, inject(min_sources, {relative: true})))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/build/'));
});
```

But this code duplication isn't solution. I think. How can I improve this part, besides to move this two array in `bower.js` file ?

Comment: Why don't you always use the minified version of third party components? You could use [main-bower-files](https://www.npmjs.com/package/main-bower-files) instead of listing all of them yourself.

Comment: For the debug purpose. Using minified version you cannot say what's wrong even if you simple forgot to import some component. So, during development I prefer to use not-minified versions of components.

Comment: You should look into [source maps](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/).

Comment: Okay. So apparently I can just provide the list of .js vendor files. And from this list create minified versions of files with maps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `config.js`. Use `var config = require('../config');` to read the variables in `config.js` so you can separate file paths and task.

If you want to separate .js and .min.js , you can use

```
'src' : [
  'src/**/*.js',
  '!src/**/*.min.js',
]
```

For example below I concat .min.js / .js files and uglify it, and also concate .css files and use cssnano() to compress it. In the end `vendor` task will output vendor.bundle.js and vendor.bundle.css

config.js:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    'vendor': {
        'scripts': {
            'src': [
                'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
                'bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.min.js',
                // Moment
                'bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js',
                'bower_components/moment/locale/zh-tw.js',
                // Ionic & Angular
                'bower_components/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js',
                'bower_components/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js'
                // ...
            ],
            'dest': 'www/js',
            'output': 'vendor.bundle.js'
        },
        'styles': {
            'src': [
                // Mobiscroll
                'bower_external/mobiscroll/css/mobiscroll.custom-2.17.0.min.css',
                ],
            'dest': 'www/css',
            'output': 'vendor.bundle.css'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

vendor.js

```
'use strict';

var config       = require('../config');
var gulp         = require('gulp');
var gulpif       = require('gulp-if');
var concat       = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify       = require('gulp-uglify');
var sourcemaps   = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var postcss      = require('gulp-postcss');
var cssnano      = require('cssnano');
var handleErrors = require('../util/handleErrors');
var browserSync  = require('browser-sync');
var pkg          = require('../../package.json');

gulp.task('vendorScripts', function () {
  return gulp.src(config.vendor.scripts.src)
    .pipe(concat(config.vendor.scripts.output))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.vendor.scripts.dest));
});

gulp.task('vendorStyles', function () {
  return gulp.src(config.vendor.styles.src)
    .pipe(concat(config.vendor.styles.output))
    .pipe(postcss([ cssnano() ]))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.vendor.styles.dest));
});

gulp.task('vendor', ['vendorScripts', 'vendorStyles']);
```